# How can I fix this issue in Android Studio

Tags: window, preview

After making a new project, I found that there is something wrong with Android Studio(I can't see the changes in design ), like adding widgets and the suggestion window doesn't appear, and the preview window shows an error(one or more layouts are missing the Layout_width or Layout_height, although, the two widgets which exist already have those attributes. The error is attached here:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Well for a start your `LinearLayout` is missing an `android:orienataion` attribute which is required. The `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes are highlighted in yellow - what warning message do you see when you hover over the yellow highlight?

Comment: Also, what happens when you click "Automatically add all missing attributes"?